# Ubuntu 18.10 halts after login

Tags: kernel, cpu, 18.10, watchdog

I am new to ubuntu just want to change from Windows. I installed Ubuntu 18.10 I tried in live mode test ubuntu and no problems I can use the OS, but after I installed it I log in and after that just loads the desktop I can move the mouse pointer for a couple of seconds and after that, it just freezes.
My laptop is an Acer VX15 i5 with Nvidia GTX 1050 Mobile.

Now I noticed that the mouse pointer or trackpad are the ones not working. If I press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, it shows a little menu. And when I press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd>, I get strange messages:

```
watchdog bug soft lockup cpu 0 stuck for 22s!
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an Acer with Ryzen 5 2500U which had soft lockup on CPU#3 (and sometimes CPU#4). This post helped me: [Ryzen/Vega laptop PCIe Bus Error](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/ryzen-vega-laptop-pcie-bus-error/124661/59)

I personally do not know if this helps Intel CPU's but it helped with Ryzen CPU's

- Basically have to add a command to grub menu in terminal `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` (need to but in your password).
- Find `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line, mine says `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
- Change it to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash processor.max_cstate=1"`.
- Exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and save.
- Update grub `sudo update-grub` and restart.

Again, I only have personal experience with this helping Ryzen, this might not help Intel at all.